# php doesn't scan relative path for files

Tags: php, file, glob

Here is my current code (that i am very proud of for my first attempt at php)

```
<?php
$files = glob("/jobops/*.txt");
$indexcount = count($files);
sort($files);
print("<br>"+$indexcount+"<br>");
foreach ($files as &$file)
{
    print("<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br>");
}
?>
```

the problem is glob again works fine in the root directory (where this script is located) but when i point it to a specific folder it returns 0 files found.

I've included a screen grab from my ftp client showing the directory structure (below)

so I'm confused what I'm doing wrong on the glob

[www.markonsolutions.com/test.php](http://www.markonsolutions.com/test.php) is where the script is and if you click it will return 0 files found

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"/jobops/*.txt"
```

is an absolute path on `*`nix, if you want to point to the directory that is in the same directory as a your php script you need to use:

```
"jobops/*.txt"
```

which is a relative path.

Comment: Or you could use "./jobops/*.txt"

Comment: In addition to this, make sure that the user in which php is running under does has access to that folder

Comment: while I don't know about actual OP's system, on error `glob` on majority of OSs will return `false`.

Comment: that worked i usually do C# programing so i know what i want just some little tweaks here and there to get it to work

thanks again for the help +1

Answer (score 3):

As said

> "/jobops/*.txt"

is an absolute path since it starts with a "**/**" (slash)

Relative paths are those not starting with a slash, so

> "jobops/*.txt"
>
> "./jobops/*.txt"
>
> "../jobops/*.txt"

are all relative ... the point is: **relative to what?**

On OSs it is relative to the directories enumerated in the environment variable PATH
(and often the current working dir is the first one listed into this variable, leding to the erroneous guess that "jobops/*.txt" is referred to the jabops dir in the current dir!)

In PHP, that is you environment, it is better to always use absolute paths, which does not implies to hard code them of course.

I suggest to do the following:

```
dirname(__FILE__).'/jobops/*.txt'
```

which is **how to use paths in PHP, correctly**

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like:

```
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/jobops/*.txt");
```

Comment: from the glob docs: *The pattern. No tilde expansion or parameter substitution is done. *

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from a web server? Could it be the User and Group settings of the web server will not allow access to other directories?  Is this a permissions issue?  Check the web server's error_log and access_logs for clues.