# Foreach glob to include files in a subdirectory

Tags: php, include, foreach, glob

I'm trying to learn how to include all the files in a directory using glob(), however I can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I have now:

```
foreach (glob("addons/*.php") as $filename) {
include $filename;
}
```

However a single file include seems to work just fine:

```
include "addons/hello.php";
```

This is what my file structure looks like:

Theme

-addons

--hello.php

-index.php

-options.php

So I'm not sure where the problem is. The code is inside a (theme) subdirectory itself, if that makes a difference at all. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $filename;` ?

Comment: Make sure `$filename` is findable in your include path.

Comment: If you use `print` in place of `include` does it give the expected list of files?

Comment: Echoing doesn't appear to do anything either.

Comment: @Gordon - Isn't that what Glob's supposed to be doing? I tried using the same path structure to include just one file, which worked w/o glob.

Comment: Same result w/ `Print`, nothing shows up.

Comment: If nothing appear, if you trying to print it ("echoing"), than it seems, that it find nothing.

Comment: I'm trying to `include` the files inside my "addon" subdirectory. Including them one at a time, as in my OP, works fine, but trying to use a `glob` statement doesn't work.

Comment: Try with `print` and `glob("x/*.php",GLOB_NOCHECK)`. It's most likely a [typo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368340/php-doesnt-scan-relative-path-for-files).

Comment: @mario - It's now saying "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" Do I have the directory path right?

Comment: I edited the OP to show my directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for testing:

```
foreach (glob("addons/*.php", GLOB_NOCHECK) as $filename) {
    PRINT $filename . "\n";
}
```

Should the directory not exist relatively to the current, then it will show `addons/*.php` as output.

Comment: Yeah, it's outputting "addons/*.php" at the top.

Comment: @James: Try `glob("./addons/*.php")` then, but you are most certainly in the wrong directory.

Comment: OK, I got it now. I finally went back enough folders. I didn't know which one was the CWD, because these were a part of the content folder. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive function should do the trick:

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) {
    $globFiles = glob("$dir/*.$ext");
    $globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
        recursiveGlob($dir, $ext);
    }

    foreach ($globFiles as $file) {
        include $file;
    }
}
```

Usage: `recursiveGlob('C:\Some\Dir', 'php');`

If you want it to do other things to the individual file, just replace the `include $file` part.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that path to file is absolute (from root of your server).

In my case this example works without problems:

```
$dir = getcwd();//can be replaced with your local path

foreach (glob("{$dir}/addons/*.php") as $filename) {
     if(file_exists($filename))
     {
         //file exists, we can include it
         include $filename;
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'File ' . $filename . ' not found<br />';
     }
};
```

Comment: On my end that just generates a list of all the files under my admin folder.

Comment: That's correct, it's show that glob is working as expected. Now you can set path to your addons folder instead of $dir variable and instead of displaying $filename use include.

Comment: It's still saying that there's no such file or directory. Don't know why because I'm using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Include is going to be using the search path which (while it typically includes the current working directory) isn't limited to that... using glob() with a relative directory path will always be relative to the current working directory. Before you enter your loop... ensure that your current working directory is where you think it is using echo getcwd()... you may find you're not in the Theme subdirectory after all; but that the Theme subdirectory is in the search path.

Comment: I would not rely on relative path as it is very easy to mess things up

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to say... relative path only works if you're in the right place. In this case, I don't think the OP is where he thinks he is.