# glob is returning no results when trying to get files from a relative path

Tags: php, php-5.6

My application is running on IIS and the physical directory structure looks something like this:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApplication\index.php
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApplication\includes\myfunctions.php
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApplication\includes\import_data\users\
```

That last folder contains 978 .cgi files which I'm trying to read data from.

`index.php` includes `includes/myfunctions.php` and makes a call to the one method in it -- `CheckForUsersToImport()` which is defined like so:

```
function CheckForUsersToImport()
{
    $usersDir = "import_data/users/";

    $globRes = glob($usersDir . "*.cgi");
    var_dump($globRes);
    
    echo "End CheckForUsersToImport();";
}
```

When I navigate to `localhost/myApplication/index.php` in my browser, I get this output:

> array(0) { } End CheckForUsersToImport();

I tried changing the second line of code to be simply `$globRes = glob("*.cgi");` but this yields the exact same output.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368340/php-doesnt-scan-relative-path-for-files) but the accepted answer did not work for me.

I've tried:

```
$usersDir = "./import_data/users/";
$usersDir = "/import_data/users/";
$usersDir = "import_data/users/";
```

But all 3 give me the exact same output as the code above.

How can I get all files with an extension of `".cgi"` in a directory two levels 'beneath' the function which is executing?

EDIT:

I updated my function as follows:

```
function checkUserData()
{
    $usersDir = "import_data/users";
    $globRes = scandir($usersDir);
}
```

When this runs, I get the following output:

> [phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/myfunctions.php on line 5: scandir(import_data/users,import_data/users): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)
>
> [phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/myfunctions.php on line 5: scandir(import_data/users): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
>
> [phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/includes/myfunctions.php on line 5: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory

Why is it looking for `scandir(import_data/users,import_data/users)` in that first error? That's not at all what I passed -- or at least, not what I think I passed -- to `scandir()`!

Comment: Check the output from `echo getcwd();` to determine if the working directory has changed.  And whenever possible, use as complete a path as you can, like `$usersDir = __DIR__ . '/import_data/users/';`

Comment: Looks like you're using phpBB - I have never developed for it, but would not be surprised if it has to `chdir()` at some point, such that the working directory isn't what you expect. I've dealt with that in Drupal before.  No idea about the strange `scandir()` error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your error messages suggest you're working within phpBB, it is possible that application has had to change the current working directory before your code executes, and your relative path is not valid where PHP is currently executing.

You can check the working directory to see if it is indeed your document root or elsewhere:

```
echo getcwd();
```

Whenever possible, specify a full path to any files or directories on disk.  In this case, I would probably use the `__DIR__` constant referring to the directory that the script defining that function is in:

```
$usersDir = __DIR__ '/import_data/users/';
```

Comment: Great; using `$usersDir = __DIR__ . "path";` I am able to get a complete list of all the files in in that directory. Thank you.